# Selenium WebDriver - Not able to access or click elements using PageObjectModel

Tags: java, selenium, object, webdriver, pageobjects

I have defined Web Elements using Page Object model in Selenium. From test method, when ever I try to access or perform any action on those web elements my test completely skips it and completes, with no error.

```
public class HomePage extends Base{

@FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='sparkButton']")
    public WebElement menuDropDown;

public HomePage(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

public void clickHomepagemenuDropDown() {
        menuDropDown.click();
        System.out.println("Print HELLO");
   }
}


public class Test1 extends Base{

  HomePage homepage = new HomePage() ;
  @Test(priority=1)
  public void homePage() throws Exception {
    try {
      //do something
        homepage.clickHomepagemenuDropDown();
      //print something
       }catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println (e);
                  return;
       }

}
```

**If I replace homepage.clickHomepagemenuDropDown();
with below lines, my program will run fine.**

```
WebElement mdd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='sparkButton']"));
mdd.click();
```

Is there some set up that I'm missing?

Update after correcting catch message--
I get following null exception
Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null

Comment: You are initializing HomePage outside of the "@Test" declaration.  Do you need to move that inside of it?  Or, do you need a "@Before" declaration to handle it?

Comment: If I initialize HomePage in a "@beforeMethod", homepage variable becomes out of scope for "@Test method".

"@BeforeMethod"
    public static void beforeM() {
     HomePage homepage = new HomePage() ;
    }

Comment: then move it inside @Test as I mentioned

Comment: Thanks that worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Test1` class you initialized `HomePage` class using field initializing so `@FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='sparkButton']")` can not find the web element. When you call `clickHomepagemenuDropDown()` in the test method, it throws an exception and it enters the catch block. In the catch block you just wrote `return`. For this reason the test skips and completes, with no error. I think you should initialize your page objects in your test methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the test class, try creating a method with beforetest/beforemethod annotation and place the object for the homepage within these methods